# Race condition when multiple processes attempts to read / delete files in the same directory

Tags: python, file-io, race-condition

I have a Python [script](https://github.com/billziss-gh/secfs.test/blob/master/fsrand/fsrand.py) which performs operations like `read`, `write` and `delete` on files in a directory. Before performing any of these operations, `os.listdir` is done to get the list of files. A file is picked at random and an operation is performed on it.

But I have to run multiple instances of the script. So there is a possibility of race condition. A file could get deleted by an instance while another instance still attempts to read it.

What is a good way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to identify the critical regions first.
Then you'll have to protect them by some kind of semaphore. This could be a lock-file or a real semaphore as offered by your operating system.

The real challenge will be to keep the critical regions (timely) as small as possible.

Since you only have to protect the script against itself, a single semaphore should do it. But if you need more than one semaphore, be sure not to use more than one at a time, or be very careful not to produce potential deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

the best approach is for you to decide what the correct behaviour should be. these are classic issues in file and database management,  a clear policy is needed first.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

# if the file exists, write to it
# if it doesn't exist, create it then write to it
# if its busy, keep trying
def race_write(doc='', text=''):

    opened = 0
    while not opened:
        try:
            with open(doc, 'w+') as f:
                f.write(str(text))
                opened = 1
        except Exception as e:
            print (e, type(e).__name__, e.args)
            print (str(doc) + ' RACE WRITE, try again...')
            pass

# if the file exists, read it and return string
# if it doesn't exist, return an empty string
# if its busy, keep trying
def race_read(doc=''):

    opened = 0
    while not opened:
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(doc):
                with open(doc, 'r') as f:
                    ret = f.read()
                    opened = 1
            else:
                opened = 1
                print (str(doc) + ' is gone, READ aborted')
                ret = ''
        except Exception as e:
            print (e, type(e).__name__, e.args)
            print (str(doc) + ' RACE READ, try again...')
            pass
        return ret

# if the file exists, repeatedly attempt to remove it until it is gone
def race_delete(doc=''):

    while os.path.isfile(doc):
        try:
            os.remove(doc)
        except Exception as e:
            print (e, type(e).__name__, e.args)
            print (str(doc) + ' RACE DELETE, try again...')
            pass
```